# Undefined reference to 'Inventory::insertEnd(Node*, int)'

Tags: c++, class, struct, append, singly-linked-list

I’m getting an “undefined reference to” error when trying to build/compile my program:

> obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
>   C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Project5Example\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to`Inventory::insertEnd(Node*, int)'|
>   ...
>   ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
>   ||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

I’m quite new to c++. What am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?
I feel is has to do with my head node? But can’t really figure out how what it is.

The error happens on main.cpp line `head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 8);`

Here is my code:

Inventory.h

```cpp
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

        struct Node
        {
            int data;
            Node* next;
        };

class Inventory
{
    public:
        // Default Constructor
        Inventory();

        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        Node *newNode(int data);
        Node* insertEnd(Node* head, int data);

    private:
        // Data members
        Node *head;
        Node *trailer;
};

#endif // INVENTORY_H
```

Inventory.cpp

```cpp
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

Inventory::Inventory()
{
    // Set the header and trailer to NULL
    head = NULL;
    trailer = NULL;
}

// Allocates a new node with given data
Node *newNode(int data)
{
    Node *new_node = new Node;
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

// Function to insert a new node at the
// end of linked list using recursion.
Node* insertEnd(Node* head, int data)
{
    // If linked list is empty, create a
    // new node (Assuming newNode() allocates
    // a new node with given data)
    if (head == NULL)
        return newNode(data);

    // If we have not reached end, keep traversing
    // recursively.
    else
        head->next = insertEnd(head->next, data);
    return head;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Inventory.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create an inventory list
    Inventory inventory1;

    Node* head = NULL;

    head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 8);
    head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 11);
    head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears you have forgotten to tell the compiler that `Node* insertEnd(Node* head, int data)` is intended to be a member function and not a free function. You want to change the definition to `Node* Inventory::insertEnd(Node* head, int data)`. Right now the linker cannot find `Inventory::insertEnd` because `insertEnd` was implemented instead.

Comment: @user4581301 you should make and answer instead of a comment

Comment: I think I will. There are a couple other issue that should be addressed, lifting this up from a small oversight.

Comment: I updated the insertEnd() function as recomended by @user4581301. I was getting a similar error for the newNode() funtion too "Undefined reference to ‘Inventory::newNode(int)” so I updated newNode function to Node Inventory::*newNode(int data) 
Now I’m getting this error 
\.cpp||In function 'Node Inventory::* newNode(int)':|
\Inventory.cpp|24|error: cannot convert 'Node*' to 'Node Inventory::*' in return|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: @tatib that's another question, please ask another question about that specific problem. As you can see, your comment is unreadable (comments are not there for posting long text and source code.

Comment: Got dragged away half way through writing my cut of the answer. Vlad covered the major points so I'm going to drop the bit I don't think he covered as well as I would have and call it a day.

Comment: In general, a linked list class should represent a linked list. It should contain all of the information required to represent the list as well as all of the functions required to manipulate the list. It should [expose as little as possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) to allow the linked list to defend itself and allow users of the linked list to [better survive changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) to the linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the structure `Node` should be a private member of the class `Inventory`. Correspondingly the class `Inventory` should not contain public member functions that have the return type `Node *`. So for example this member function

```
Node *newNode(int data);
```

should be removed. In turn this public member function

```
Node* insertEnd(Node* head, int data);
```

should be declared like

```
void insertEnd( int data );
```

If it is required (but it is not required) the function could call a private static member function declared like

```
static Node* insertEnd(Node* head, int data);
```

As you declared a two-sided singly-linked list then it does not make sense to define the function `insertEnd` as a recursive function because there is no recursion. A new node ia appended to the node that you named like `trailer` though it would be better to name it like `tail`.

Moreover in the definitions of the functions `newNode` and `insertEnd` you forgot to specify name of the class Inventory like

```
Node * Inventory::newNode(int data)
{
    //...
}

Node * Inventory::insertEnd(Node* head, int data)
{
    //...
}
```

And this part in main

```
Inventory inventory1;

Node* head = NULL;

head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 8);
head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 11);
head = inventory1.insertEnd(head, 20);
```

does not make sense. The object `inventory1` already contains the data member `head` (and `trailer`) that should be updated for the object.

The class can be defined for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

class Inventory
{
public:
    Inventory() = default;

    Inventory( const Inventory & ) = delete;
    Inventory & operator =( const Inventory & ) = delete;

    ~Inventory();

    void insertEnd( int data );

    void clear();

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const Inventory & );

private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;
};

Inventory::~Inventory()
{
    clear();
}

void Inventory::insertEnd( int data )
{
    Node *node = new Node { data, nullptr };

    if ( tail == nullptr )
    {
        head = tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = tail->next = node;
    }
}

void Inventory::clear()
{
    while ( head != nullptr )
    {
        Node *node = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete node;
    }

    tail = head;
}

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Inventory &inventory )
{
    for ( Inventory::Node *node = inventory.head; node != nullptr; node = node->next )
    {
        os << node->data << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

int main()
{
    Inventory inventory;

    for ( const auto &data : { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } )
    {
        inventory.insertEnd( data );
    }

    std::cout << inventory << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```